# What is the difference between UIButton and MyCustomButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is the difference between UIButton and MyCustomButton
UIButton *bttn;
MyCustomButton *bttn1;

Comment: you should post some code in order to receive a response that could help you. The MyCustomButton class could be a subclass of UIButton but i'm just speculating...

Comment: Also, go accept some answers on your previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Custom UIButton Creation u design as per your need. Like background image setting and different customize as you want.UIButton functionality it should be in the same default button format.For details [1]: http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-uibutton-manually-on-iphone.html  refer it..

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `MyCustomButton` is some button implementation subclassing `UIButton` but is not part of UIKit by default. It will probably extend `UIButton`'s functionality but without knowing its implementation nobeody will be able to porpose further details.